# On an AD joined macOS, the home folder stops auto mounting when switching to mobile accounts

Tags: mac-osx

We have one AD integrated iMac in our company that is used by a couple of users.

Our AD user accounts have set the following attributes:

- `homeDirectory` = `\\ad.example.com\Shares\UserHomeFolders$\%username%`

In the Directory Utility ([example screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwbR0.png)) we set the following options.

```
[ ] Create mobile account at login
[x] Force local gome directory on startup disk
[x] Use UNC path from Active Directory to derive network home location
```

So when any of the users log on to the iMac, the `homeDirectory` path is automatically mounted and visible in the bottom bar (can't remember name, please edit if you know it) represented by a globe icon.

So far so good.

We have two issues with that approach:

1. The logon screen need about 20-40 seconds to eventually show the "Other…" login option.
2. The logon as an AD user only works, when there is a connection to the AD server.

So we decided to migrate our users to mobile accounts. That is where the problem arises.

After moving a user to a mobile account, the `homeDirectory` isn't mounted anymore. In fact, running `mount` in the terminal doesn't show any network share being mounted anywhere.

So my question is: Why does my mobile account not mount the `homeDirectory` when a network account does?